# How to read decimal data of 38 precision and 18 scale in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I have data of type Decimal(38,16) in RDBMS. I am importing that data into HDFS(Hadoop) in parquet file format. After that, I am reading that parquet file into Spark code.

```
val df = spark.read.parquet(<path>)
```

Once data loaded into Spark dataframe the datatype of that column converted to double. It is round up the value of `cnt` column to 14 digits after the decimal point while I have 16 digits after the decimal point.

**Schema:**

```
scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- cnt: double (nullable = true)
```

In order solve this I have to take a simple example.

For example,

```
val dt = Array(1,88.2115557137985,223.7658213615901501)
```

**Output:**

```
scala> dt.foreach(println)
1.0
88.2115557137985
223.76582136159016
```

But here I am expecting as it is data without round up the value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The example array and the schema you've provided don't match. It is not clear what you are asking. Scala 2.11.8 repl shows output as input without rounding. Do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 3):

You can predefine your schema to make the high-precision column `DecimalType` when reading the Parquet file:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val customSchema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("id", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("cnt", DecimalType(38, 16), true)
))

val df = spark.read.schema(customSchema).parquet("/path/to/parquetfile")
```